# Add a field (Sql or List) in article options with a search bar inside in Joomla 4

Tags: joomla-4.x, joomla-4

I added a field type "sql" to show a list of options in the Article Options in Joomla 4. But I need to add a field like this with a search box inside to looking for one of the voices typing part of the options (because the options are many).

So, I need something like this:

[image]

I noticed that in Joomla 3 someone used "formbehavior.chosen" to do this, but this function is applied to every list in the Article Options, and I don't want it. I want this behavior, this search box in a list, only for a specific list.

Is there a way in Joomla 4 to do this in a simple way? Can I just set an attribute in the field element of the XML file to do this? Thank you :)

Comment: Welcome Nintendomi.  Please take our [tour] while you wait for feedback/support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In J4 you can use `joomla.form.field.list-fancy-select` layout for list fields. To use in XML form, add `layout` attribute to the field:

```
layout="joomla.form.field.list-fancy-select"
```

Comment: Great, it works perfectly! Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is interested in a more recent method (Joomla 4.3 and upwards):

When you edit the list type custom field (or SQL custom field type), go to the tab "Options" and at the "Form Options", the item "Layout" has an option named "Enhanced select".

This will add a modern search (and match).